# How to convert a emf image file into PNG format in Azure web app

Tags: azure

I want to convert a emf image file into PNG format.It works in local machine. But while running it in azure does not give a correct output. It gives only blank image frame.What should I do?

Comment: Could you please post more relevant codes about how you convert the emf image to PNG? Which library you have used? Do you store the png file into the site's folder? If you could post more details information, it will be more easily for us to find the reason and solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and your profile, I suggest you could use  System.Drawing.Image class to convert the emd to png.

I also created a test demo and publish it to the azure, it works well.

More details, you could refer to this codes:

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(@"/image/test.Emf"));

        image1.Save(Server.MapPath(@"/image/test2.png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

If you use another way and still face this issue, I suggest you could post more relevant codes for us to repro your issue.